# Theoretical rechargeable battery capacity question

Tags: lithium-ion, battery-storage

I have very little energy usage/storage knowledge but my question will hopefully prove to be a simple one.

If I have a 120 volt appliance that uses roughly 0.50 kWh a day and 600 watts at peak draw, is there a reasonably sized rechargeable battery (think large laptop) that could, in theory, supply this for 18 hours and be adequately recharged nightly.

Thanks in advance for any insight....

Comment: A normal car battery holds about 1 kWh. A laptop battery is about 50 Wh. A _laptop-sized_ Li-ion battery would put you in the range of 500 Wh if you consider a 17” laptop.

Comment: People are quibbling over your units. Did you MEAN 0.5 kWh/day which equals 500 Wh/24 ~= 20 Watts mean with 600 W peak. **OR** 500 Watts mean and 600 Watts peak.

Comment: Yes @RussellMcMahon your first interpretation is the correct one. There appliance consumes typically .5kWh a day, total and draws, at max, 600 W (peak) occasionally.

Comment: @winny thanks for clarification. Yes I was referring to the size of a 17" laptop's battery. Not the size of the entire laptop. If the only way to supply .5 kWh is with a battery the size of an entire laptop, then I'll need to rethink the project as that is definitely not a manageable enough size.

Comment: Your standard 17” laptop comes with 70-120 Wh battery depending on model, so you do fall short here.

Comment: Using: 500 Wh in a day. A single LiIon cell at 3.6V mean nominal requires Ah = 500/3.6 ~= 140 Ah. A good 18650 call is 3300 Mah (3.3 Ah) so you'd need 140/3.3 ~=  42 of them [!!!]. || Using a 12V battery Ah needed = 500/12 = 42 Ah. That's a largish car battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** an easy "compact battery" application.

Required:

- Battery that stores 500 Wh (Watt.hours) of energy.
- Assumed means of converting battery power to mains power.
- **Conversion efficiency assumed to be 100%**  adjust to whatever converter is used.

Required Battery Ah (amp-hours) = Watt.hours /  battery voltage.
ie Ah = Wh/V
So:

**Lithium Ion:**

A single LiIon cell at 3.6V mean nominal requires
Ah = Wh/V = 500/3.6 ~= 140 Ah.

A good 18650 cell is 3300 mAh (3.3 Ah) so you'd need 140/3.3 ~=  42 of them [!!!].

Recent 21700 LiIon cells may have 4 AH capacity for high power cells and up to about 5 Ah for high energy (and lower peak power) cells. So you'd need 140/4 or 140/5 = 36 or 28 of these respectively. 28 x 21700 cells at 21mm dia x 70mm long could be arranged in a 4 x 7 stack of about 100mm x 175mm x 70 mm (about 4" x 7" x 3").
Reputable cells from a trustable supplier cost in the $5 - $7 range each.
600 Watts peak draw = 600/28 ~= 21 Watts/cell. [Yes, that IS a valid equation :-) ].
I at 21 Watts/cell = W/V = 21/3.6 = 5.8A. That's about 1.5C or less and available from all except the lowest power rated 21700 cells.

Once you know the required battery size you still need to know how to safely configure them into a battery of series and parallel cells and then operate an inverter from them. Unless you are severely $ constrained it is usually a good idea to buy battery packs & chargers 'off the shelf' and also you need to be sure to not lower the battery voltage too low during discharge.

I'll repeat - "this is not an easy compact battery question" - it's all doable, but it's also easy to do it wrong enough to be disastrous, sadly.

**______________________________________**

**Lead Acid**

Using a 12V battery Ah needed = 500/12 = 42 Ah. That's a largish car battery fully discharged.

**__________________________________**

**Internal combustion engine:**

A small internal combustion engine driving an alternator using alcohol or "petrol" would typically require around 0.5 litre of fuel to supply 500 Watt hours of energy.
[Fuel energy content ~~ 10 kWh/litre. Assume all up somewhat pessimistic 10% efficiency in energy conversion].

Comment: Perfect. Your lithium ion cell explanation was exactly the information I needed but didn't know how to ask for.

Comment: @jaxwithanx Once you know the required battery size you still need to know how to safely configure them into a battery of series and parallel cells and then operate an inverter from them. Unless you are severely $ constrained it is usually a good idea to buy battery packs & chargers 'off the shelf' and also you need to be sure to not lower the battery voltage too low during discharge. As I said "this is not an easy compact battery question" - it's all doable, but it's also easy to do it wrong enough to be disastrous, sadly.

Comment: Yes for sure, this is very early in the game so it was very much a 'theoretical' question.  Basically, I'm trying to determine if an appliance I currently use could feasibly run off a rechargeable li-ion battery instead of being plugged in.

The dimensions of said appliance would actually lend itself well to arranging the batteries in a 2x14 pattern.  It's very early in the game and the appliance has some opportunity to actually draw less power than I originally stated but I just wanted a loose idea if current battery technology could get close to supplying adequate power.  It seems it can.